# Methodology for a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm undertaking a rather large conversion from a legacy database-driven Windows app to a Rails app. Because of the large number of forms and database tables involved, I want to make sure I've got the right methodology before getting too far.

My chief concern is minimizing the amount of code I have to write. There are many models that interact together, and I want to make sure I'm using them correctly. Here's a simplified set of models:

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :PatientAddresses
  has_many :PatientFileStatuses
end

class PatientAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Patient
end

class PatientFileStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Patient
end

The controller determines if there's a Patient selected; everything else is based on that.

In the view, I will be needing data from each of these models. But it seems like I have to write an instance variable in my controller for every attribute that I want to use. So I start writing code like this:

@patient = Patient.find(session[:patient])
@patient_addresses = @patient.PatientAddresses
@patient_file_statuses = @patient.PatientFileStatuses

@enrollment_received_when = @patient_file_statuses[0].EnrollmentReceivedWhen
@consent_received = @patient_file_statuses[0].ConsentReceived
@consent_received_when = @patient_file_statuses[0].ConsentReceivedWhen

The first three lines grab the Patient model and its relations. The next three lines are examples of my providing values to the view from one of those relations.

The view has a combination of text fields and select fields to show the data above. For example:

"val1", "val2"=>"val2", "Written"=>"Written"}, :include_blank=>true )%>
:force %>

(BTW, the select tag isn't really working; I think I have to use collection_select?)

My questions are:

1. Do I have to manually declare the value of every instance variable in the controller, or can/should I do it within the view?
2. What is the proper technique for displaying a select tag for data that's not the primary model?
3. When I go to save changes to this form, will I have to manually pick out the attributes for each model and save them individually? Or is there a way to name the fields such that ActiveRecord does the right thing?

Thanks in advance,
Aaron.

Comment: whats with the camel case notation in your associations?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to manually declare the value of every instance variable in the controller, or can/should I do it within the view?

As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid defining instance variables in your views; especially if it's call to a model. It can be confusing to maintain, more difficult to test and cannot be reused.

> What is the proper technique for displaying a select tag for data that's not the primary model?

Provided that the "secondary" models are associated with the "primary" model, you can chain methods together. When you define an association in your model, you'll get [these methods for free](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

```
# Where attr is an attr belonging to the patient_address which is 
# associated with the patient
<%= @patient.patient_address.attr %>
```

> When I go to save changes to this
>   form, will I have to manually pick out
>   the attributes for each model and save
>   them individually? Or is there a way
>   to name the fields such that
>   ActiveRecord does the right thing?

You will be interested in the [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001890) method for nesting associated models in a single form. [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) also has some great examples of working with associated models in forms.

Answer (score 0):

1)
 There is nothing stopping you from writing arbitrary Ruby code in the view, so you can just write `@patient.PatientAddresses`, instead of defining `@patient_addresses` in the controller. That is just boiler-plate anyway and very easy to refactor with search/replace, if you wish to change it later. OTOH I would put the line

`@patient = Patient.find(session[:patient])`

in the controller, since you only want to perform the look-up once and the query might also change.

3)
 The `save` method in `ActiveRecord` is a bit subtle. In general, it will save only the object on which you invoke the method *as well as any dependencies*. It may not be possible to save just one row, if that row has a foreign key relation with another table. This means that for the code

`patient = Patient.new; file_status.patient = patient`

`patient` would be saved automatically when calling `file_status.save`, since the `id` for `patient` must be generated for the foreign key relation. Calling `patient.save` would *not* save `file_status` however.

If you want the associated objects to be saved along with the `Patient` you can specify `:autosave => true` when defining the `has_many` relation.

The details are in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).